# Synchronise(!) 60000 ms Loop on every device. NO INACCURACY

Tags: javascript, loops, time, synchronization

this goes out to the most most professionals among you.

I am planing a Never-Ending-Loop of an (Javascript)-one-minute-animation.

```
The complete Animation ends after 59.999 Milliseconds. 

-> Tween 1 starts at 0 ms
-> Tween 2 starts at 1000 ms
-> Tween 3 starts at 2000 ms
-> Tween 4 starts at 3000 ms
-> Tween 5 starts at 4000 ms
-> Tween 6 starts at 5000 ms

...loop
```

so far, so good.

**I want, that the Loop is Synchronised on every device, on every operating system, any Browser, from anywhere arround the world exactly in Milliseconds. NO INACCURACY.**

*My try was: get the Seconds (to know the tween-no.) and Milliseconds (to know, when the next tween starts) of Server-Time via Ajax. And then, let the animation start at Tween(x) after x Milliseconds. But it is not synchronised. There are up to 2 Seconds difference.*

How do i have to fix it? Please dont say, it is not possible, it has to be possible anywhere!

If its not possible with javascript, tell me something else.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It takes time to request something (anything) from the server. That "up to 2 seconds" is latency and processing time. It's impossible to get perfect consistency using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, but what else can solve this problem?

Comment: "No inaccuracy" isn't a meaningful requirement.  You need to decide how much inaccuracy is allowed.  As you have found, it's easy to get to 2 seconds accuracy.  The difficulty (and cost) will increase to infinity the closer you get to perfect accuracy.

Comment: Well, it's not really clear what you're trying to do. You're not going to get perfect synchronization on a global basis. The best you can do is use sockets, and there will still be a tiny lag. You can try to reduce it by estimating latency (for example, record the time client-side, send a request, measure the time elapsed before the response is received, and divide by 2), but you can't eliminate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time sync between server & browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957733/time-sync-between-server-browser)

Comment: Lets say, I want to animate a special Headline on my webpage. 6 Times in 1 Minute, and then loop. the Increase on the different devices should not be more then 500 Milliseconds.

Comment: I´ve tried [link] (https://github.com/NodeGuy/ServerDate), but no accuracy under 500 ms

Answer (score 0):

The most brutal would be to implement [NTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1305) but if half a second difference is enough you can implement a simplified version.

The main method is to start a communication between a time server and the client to get a) the time and b) the difference between the client time and server time. With a small serverprogram that is nothing more than a stopwatch you can do the following:

server -> client: server time (or start with client->server)

client: sets own time to server time

client -> server: client time

(you may repeat it a couple of times to get an average)

The serve can calculate the lag time now and send it to the client and the client corrects its time accordingly. You canot set the computer time of the client in Javascript, you can only set the time for the actual session, so you need it to repeat for every reload and in between, too, once in a while (not too often, I would say that once every hour is more than sufficient).

The overhead should be as small as possible, it would be a good idea to use a smaller protocol than HTTP if possible

A small and hastily knocked up example with PHP on the server side:

```
<?php
  $client_ts = $_GET["date"];
  // UTC timestamp in milliseconds
  $server_ts = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
  // send back that timestamp and the lag
  echo $server_ts."|".($client_ts - $server_ts);
?>
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>LAG test</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
td,th {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: .5ex .5em .5ex .5em;
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  margin: 3ex 1em 0 4em;
}
p {
  max-width: 40em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// everything is highly simplified and crude here! No checks, no balances!

// Simple AJAX. Websockets would be better, of course, but also way more complex
var ajax_request;
function get_data(){
  var ret, lag, diff,client_time, server_time;
  if (ajax_request.readyState === 4){
    if (ajax_request.status === 200){
      ret = ajax_request.responseText;
    }
    else{
      ret = null;
    }
  }
  else {
    ret = null;
  }
  if(ret){
    // only one check here, more are better especially
    // if 'diff' is very large
    client_time = Date.now();
    server_time = ret.split("|");
    lag = server_time[1];
    diff = Math.abs(client_time - server_time[0]);

    document.getElementById("ctos").textContent = lag;
    document.getElementById("stoc").textContent = diff;
    document.getElementById("diff").textContent = (lag - diff);
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ctos").textContent = "Nope";
    document.getElementById("stoc").textContent = "Nada";
    document.getElementById("diff").textContent = "Rien";
  }
}

function sendTo(text,uid,url){
  ajax_request  = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax_request.open("GET", url + "?date=" + text + "u=" + uid, true);
  ajax_request.send(null);
  ajax_request.onreadystatechange = get_data;
}

function testLAG(){
  // cheap pseudo-UID to avoid caching
  var unifier = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffffff).toString();
  // date.now() returns UTC time
  var client_time = Date.now();
  sendTo(client_time,unifier ,"phpdate.php");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> To test lag, press LAG-Button</h1>
<p>The difference in "Diff." is the probablity that it was the same route both ways. You need to allow for some milliseconds for the HTTP overhead but in general: the lower the better.</p>
<table id="out" caption="latencies">
<tr><th>Client to Server</th><th>Server to Client</th><th>Diff.</th></tr>
<tr><td id="ctos">n/a</td><td id="stoc">n/a</td><td id="diff">n/a</td>
</table>
<input type="button" value="LAG-Button" onclick="testLAG()" /> &lt;- press here and press often. But only if you don't mind.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks deamentiaemundi, but isnt it the same as the do here (github.com/NodeGuy/ServerDate) ?

Comment: No. They just read the server's time, hope for a small lag and use it. It is one-sided, only the client is active. To measure latency you need to communicate with the server. Both the client and the server have to exchange timestamps and both have to calculate the difference and communicate the results. If you do it right, you can get a precision of some hundred picoseonds(!) (although not with HTTP and Javascript). vid. e.g.: http://www.ntp.org/rfc.html.

Comment: wow! Is the diff the time, when i have to start with the nearest animation-tween?

Comment: The diff is just the indicator to tell if both routes were about the same/differently. If they are roundabout the same, take the average and set the client clock to server time  assuming the server has the correct time. Do it again. You'll get a good aproximation of the latency the second time. Adjust client clock again, include the latency this time. Be aware that the client clock can be waaaay off at the start, even into the future!

Comment: If i use the click-button, my result shows a range between 70 to 89 ms difference, but if I use  'setInterval(function(){ testLAG(); }, 1000);' it shows a range between 80 to 400 ms difference.

Comment: I do not know what that test should have tested but I get the slight feeling that you have not the best idea of what I tried to do with my code. My code is a not-so-small hint about how to synchronize the client clock with the server clock within an error of 0.5 seconds. Once you have the clocks in sync you can start the animation at a given time that is within 0.5 seconds on all clients that run that animation. My code lacks the actual clock-setting, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: deamentiaemundi: you have to help me: I m not getting it. How do I have to write the script to sync. all different Browsers and operating systems worldwide with my animation? I have used your code, but it is not sync. to the different devices. and if a Smartphone goes to sleep, the sync. becomes fail. It will help me a lot, if you write the code for me.

Comment: I showed you how to synchronize the clocks of server and client within the small margin of error you accepted. Now you can assume that the UTC time is the same on all clients (some *very* old or *very* niche browsers might not support it) and you can start your animation on all clients at the same UTC time. What else do you need? No. serious, I don't get the exact nature of your problem. You might consider to ask a new question based on the code you already have because the comment section is not the best way to post large amounts of code.